# N2 diffusion through a vertical fluid column

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, fluid-dynamics, chemistry

Trying to figure out the mathematical model that might correlate to laboratory results.

I have a cylindrical pressure vessel (picture a can) with height, h, and radius, r. It is filled with distilled water and held at a high ambient hydro-static pressure, P. From the bottom of the can (h=0), I release N2 gas into the vessel at flowrate, f. Using Henry's Law, the gas diffuses into the liquid very quickly because of pressure P. If I have an N2 sensor on the top of the vessel....how long will it take for it to start seeing concentrations of N2 resulting from the input at the bottom of the vessel?

I know this has to do with Fick's law but I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is as follows.

The model with one-dimensional fick diffusion 
[image]

where C(x,t) is the concentration of the N2; *n* is the diffusivity of the N2 in water.

The solution is

[image]

An approximated time for the sensor response is

[image]

Comment: You have not gotten into how the cross sectional $C(h,t)$ relates back to the volumetric $C(x,t)$. $r$ and I think $P$ both enter the problem through this connection. You also might comment for the OP that you have used the Fourier series/separation of variables method here. You also might mention the limitations of the 1D model (essentially you are assuming either perfect mixing or uniform injection of gas at the bottom).

Comment: The solution c(x,t) is a Fourier series with sinusoids but I am only showing the concentration at the top of vessel it is to say when x = h.  Then the sinusoids are evaluated and the series only contains exponential terms.  Do your agree?

Comment: I actually just forgot that the initial condition was zero, sorry about that. My comment has had a couple edits. (I can't fix this one now: I meant to say perfect mixing along the cross sections, which is guaranteed in the limit $r \ll h$, or when the diffusion is appropriately anisotropic).

Comment: I think that approximately the problem can be considered as one-dimensional.  Do you agree?

Comment: I am not sure, because there are some gaps in the specification of the problem. The main gap is that we do not know how $r$ compares to $h$ and we do not know how the gas is injected at the bottom of the cylinder. I would not be surprised if the gas was injected through a hole in the bottom of the cylinder which is much smaller than the bottom itself. If this is true and $r$ is comparable to $h$ then there would be significant error in the use of a 1D model. (Of course the 3D model is attacked by the same method, only the calculation is a little bit longer.)

Comment: @Ian, you are very right, there are many gaps but I  think  that the one-dimensional solution gives an insight about the response time.  Do you agree?

Comment: Unless the cylinder is quite stout (i.e. $h \ll r$), which is not typical for experiments with gases, I agree. In particular it is useful to know that the response time should be at least roughly proportional to $h^2$.

Comment: @Ian, please look at http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00986445.2012.695302#abstract

Comment: @Ian, h>>r in this instance.

Comment: If $h \gg r$ then Juan's answer is just fine for your needs. (Though it would be interesting to see what the second term in the $r/h$ expansion is...)

Answer (score 0):

Assume P=2000 psi, what is the impact of pressure gradient on the response time of detector ?

Will temperature have any effect on response time?